# Lean virtualization solutions

Tags: virtualization

I am looking for a lightweight way to run a linux kernel guest under an OSX host. I need only to be able to boot a very minimal linux kernel, start a single process under it, and communicate with that process through a network connection. I do not need any kind of display virtualization. I am aware of VMware and VirtualBox but I'm looking for something more minimal. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/mist64/xhyve

Answer (score 1):

Why not give [Docker - Build, Ship, and Run Any App, Anywhere](https://www.docker.com/) a try?